# JSP Session and Bean confusion

Tags: jsp, session

I'm trying to setup a basic session in JSP but I'm getting myself in a muddle.

I have a login page that then runs a Login.java files that will access the database and confirm the details, it will also create a Bean to store data. The username that the person entered is then stored in the Bean.

However it doesn't seem to be storing it, or it's getting overwritten or something.

Each page has the following code :

```
< jsp:useBean id="userBean" class="UserBean" scope="session"/>
< jsp:setProperty name="userBean" property="*"/>
```

When the .java file tries to redirect back to the homepage the username is still set to null, what's going on here?

Comment: Sessions are backed by cookies. Does your browser have cookies enabled? Check the HTTP traffic to be sure. Oh, please do not insert spaces after the `<`. It only causes red herrings. Just read the editor's help how to format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your bean needs to be in a package. Something like 
class="yourPackage.UserBean"

Comment: While true (packageless classes only works in certain Tomcat versions), but if that were the cause of the problem, the OP would have faced a JSP exception with the message `The value for the useBean class attribute UserBean is invalid`, not the behaviour OP is describing.